# Help with pulling company fundamentals from EDGAR

Tags: equities, data, fundamentals, sec, edgar

I need help understanding why there are many different values for a specific metric reported by a company's *10-K* or *10-Q* in the EDGAR database.

I've downloaded the entire US equity universe in JSON from the SEC website [here](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/sec-api-documentation) (Bulk Data).

Here is my code for getting the Diluted Earnings Per Share of a company in 2016

```
import json
import pandas as pd

f = open('CIK0001511198.json')
data = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['facts']['us-gaap']['EarningsPerShareDiluted']['units']['USD'])

df = df[(df['form'] == '10-K') | (df['form'] == '10-Q')]

df[df['fy'] == 2016]
```

[image]

I was expecting 4 rows with three *10-Q* and one *10-K*... some values are different even within the same form id (`accn`)

Can someone explain why there are many different values and what the differences are?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should check Bamsec for one of the stocks manually to see what's going on, and what the "val" column is actually referring to. Manually compare those results w/ what you see here.

It could be something like the company amending the 10-K which leads to two entries in this dataset.

It could be that the company reports data for previous FY as well as current FY inside the same 10-K, which leads to two rows being entered into this dataset for the one report.